# Stack level too deep error when attempting to resize browser window - Capybara

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I need to resize my browser windown in order for my tests to run correctly or I get an error stating that element cannot be inteacted with, other element would receive the click.

So I attempt to resize the browser window. My code looks like this:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1800, 1800)
```

However I get a stack level too deep error. I am pretty sure I am using the window.resize_to method correctly. I have also tried using this method:

```
def set_selenium_window_size(width, height)
window = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.window
window.resize_to(width, height)
end
```

and then caling the method after I register the driver but again I get the stack level too deep error.

Has anyone else seen this and how did you get around it?

Comment: Can you post the details of the error?

Comment: Hi Vince. There is very little details regarding the error. I am running the test via the terminal and all I get is: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Comment: Actually the entire error message is:  stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
      /Users/Gerry/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/cucumber-1.3.2/lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:73

Comment: Interestingly this only happens for Chrome Driver. If I omit the chrome driver part and have the following:    `Capybara.default_selector = :css`
`Capybara.default_driver = :selenium`
`Capybara.run_server = false`                             `pagedriver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1800, 1800)`           This results in Firefox browser been launched and it is resized without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

[It's a known bug of Chromedriver](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=297)